# Java 7 SSL changes with Java 6

Tags: java, ssl

I have some SSL code that works perfectly fine with 1.6 but fails with 1.7 and 1.8.
Using -Djavax.net.debug=all I have checked the difference between the logs, and a few things strike me (comparing 1.6.0_43 with 1.7.0_60)

First difference is that Java 7/8 shows:

```
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
```

etc.

whereas Java 6 does not have this.

The cipher suites for Java 6 are:

```
Cipher Suites: [SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5, SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
```

and for 1.7:

```
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
```

There are some common suites between the two.

Also, I can see the length in protocols during handshakes...

Java 6 ends up with

--> SSLSession: Peer Host: MYIP:443, Cipher Suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, Protocol: TLSv1, Id: ....

But Java 7:

```
main, handling exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = internal_error
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 01 00 02 02 50                               ......P
main, called closeSocket()
main, IOException in getSession():  javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
--> debugSession(..)null
```

So.. according to this link https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/CipherSuites

The cipher suites have changed a lot during 6, 7, 8

Question A: It seems to be a server cipher suites issues - not compliant with Java 7/8, would you agree? Which means that the only solution to solve this Java 7/8 SSL cipher suite issue is to add all Java 6 Cipher Suites (Ok - I know they are weak - to the java.security cert file)

Question B: Has anyone faced a similar issue, and how did you fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Hi,

Ok.. just to help others if you are facing a similar issue, it seems that it is a "code" issue with adverse consequences on Java 7, 8 the way we handle our SSL connections.

Our code was installing a X509TrustManager to validate the server domains.
This seems to fail the handshake with 7, 8 but not with 6...

Thanks

Comment: Also, our previous implementation of the trust manager was throwing exception for not supported methods, and it seems that 7 & 8 dont support this doing the following helped for both 7, 8 but also 6: do not throw in checkClientTrusted and return an empty array for getAcceptedIssuers

Comment: It's not clear whether you're implementing a client or a server. `checkClientTrusted` will only be called if you're setting up a server that verifies a client certificate (and that shoudn't have changed between Java 6, 7 and 8). Besides this, which platform are you running this on?

Comment: It is client - Windows 7 for the tests. Problem is solved as previous comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to my cryptic exception is that in 1.6, we implemented X509TrustManager as follows,

```
@Override
public void checkClientTrusted(final X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType) throws CertificateException {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}

@Override
public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

But in 1.7/1.8, we needed to do this (also works with 1.6)

```
    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(final X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType) throws CertificateException {
    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return new X509Certificate[]{};
    }
```

Comment: Totally helped me with an issue I was facing with `javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`